# Как убрать боковой скролл, но при этом чтобы футер был прижат прижат к низу страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как убрать боковой скролл, но при этом чтобы футер был прижат прижат к низу страницы? именно прижат к низу страницы а не экрана не (position:fixed)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте Ваш код, чтобы можно было Вам помочь!

Comment: Для прижатия подвала есть отличное решение на flexbox https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810588/197801

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать для body "height: 100%" или "overflow: hidden"

Comment: а если появился двойной скролл вертикальный?)